# Myth of a safe .env file. Why still gitignore it while it is included in a client-side bundle anyway?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, environment-variables

There is a myth of a safe .env file, as one of the articles puts it:

> Not only that, they keep our deepest, darkest secrets as web developers. They make sure that our precious API keys and database passwords are kept locally, away from prying eyes.

The thing is that **content of .env file ends up in a bundle and is publicly available client-side**. All you need to do is to open DevTools, go to Source tab and search all code by name of one of your "secret variables".

I remember that discovering that for the first time was kind of disappointing. I was as well a victim of a false narrative about "safe .env variables where we can put all our secrets".

Given that it actually becomes public, why do we still respect this ritual with gitignoring .env and pretending we are hiding something? Is .env only a clever way to keep together several handy variables in one place and nothing more?

Has anyone still have good arguments why we should not make it a part of git history?

I read many articles about .env and found out that they are spreading a false narrative and even a bit dangerous. One could believe that .env is a safe place tu put your passwords and secrets and is somehow magically hidden everywhere.

Comment: By default Webpack does no such thing. If you are asking why yours is embedding secrets, you'll need to share your Webpack config.

Comment: It makes some sense for a package that is only deployed on a server. For browser-side code, no it does not make sense. And I would argue that things like API keys and database passwords should never be kept that way; they should not be stored in anything other than an encrypted keystore, and server processes should require manual startup with ephemeral passwords provided by actual people typing them in through a secure (non-persisting) mechanism.

Comment: "*Given that it actually becomes public, why do we still respect this ritual with gitignoring .env and pretending we are hiding something?*" good question. The workings of client and server code are ***very*** well known. Frontend code is ***(in)famously*** not to contain any secrets. There is nothing magical about .env files where just using them for frontend code somehow makes the content both readable and not readable at the same time. Do not relegate what should be common knowledge to to a blind religion. Application settings (what .env files are) are also a well-known concept.

Comment: "*Has anyone still have good arguments why we should not make it a part of git history?*" on that note - you've not presented an argument *for* adding them to the commit history. Increasing the attack vector is hardly something you are endorsing, right? Because an application which has never been deployed can still leak credentions via the commit history. Your example is just that a *deployed*, *reachable*, and *client-side* application (three conditions) leaks credentials. Yet you are essentially asking "why shouldn't we drop two of the three conditions for a breach?"